# Insert foldable A3 pages in an A4 document with active references

Tags: hyperref, page-numbering, book-design

I am at the end of a big LaTeX document (my thesis) and I would like to insert A3 tables and figures in the Annexes (Supporting informations) section. These A3 pages would be foldable and ideally I would like to have them page-numbered twice on the recto (so that ounce folded they look like single A4 page). Ideally they would be LaTeX-coded so that `hyperref`, inclusion in ToC and `chemcompounds` package (a package allowing automatic numbering of chemical compounds) would be active. Whould this be possible ?
As a picture worth a thousand word, here it is :

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your specifications for (some of) the appendix pages. I take it that you want the physical size of the appendix pages to be A3/landscape; the recto should be in two-column format, with each column given a separate page number; the verso, in contrast, should be in single-column format and not contain a page number (to judge from the images).

Assuming that this interpretation is on target, the layout requirement could be rephrased as stating that every third logical page in the appendix has to be in A3/landscape/unnumbered format. Assuming that you're fine with 25mm margins on all four sides of the large page, your objective could be achieved by (i) loading the `afterpage` and `changepage` packages in the preamble, (ii) creating a new environment called `hugepage` as follows:

```
\newenvironment{hugepage}%
  {\clearpage
   \pagestyle{empty}  % turn off display of page numbers, headers, ...
   \changepage{247mm}{370mm}{25mm}{25mm}{}{}{}{}{}} % switch to A3
  {\addtocounter{page}{-1} % decrement "page" counter variable by 1
   \clearpage
   \changepage{160mm}{247mm}{25mm}{25mm}{}{}{}{}{}} % back to A4
```

and (iii) adding the following code on the even-numbered (logical) page of the recto (physical) page:

```
\afterpage{%
\begin{hugepage}
... code that goes onto the huge page ...
\end{hugepage}}
```

Of course, the precise values of the arguments of the `\changepage` command will depend on the actual layout of your document (which you haven't stated, which is why I'm assuming for simplicity margins of 25mm on all four sides).

With this design, all cross-references will work as usual, including those to items on the un-numbered (verso) large pages. The only thing that's not going to work properly is the `\pageref` command to something that's on an unnumbered page... Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, I've ran the code and it seems to take into account the change of format in the page (from A4 to A3) but i dont see anything changing on my pdf output, the supposed A3 page is like other A4 pages ... is there something I'm missing ? (running PdfTex) Thank you !

Comment: adding \pdfpagewidth=2\pdfpagewidth  after \afterpage{%
\begin{hugepage}
I get a better output on my pdf file  that is a landscape A3 page but the margin comportement is weird. The text is not stopping on the right. I don't get it ...

Comment: Do you have Acrobat (or Reader, or other pdf page viewer) set to automatically resize and/or rotate pages to make them fit the 'default' paper size (A4)? If so, you need to turn off that setting (and also direct the pages in question to an A3 output tray, of course).

Comment: About the "margin comportment": You haven't provided information on the margins you'd like, so I had to make some educated guesses -- which, in the end, may or may not meet your needs. :-(

Comment: About Acrobat. If I just use plain \pdfpagewidth=2\pdfpagewidth   I get an A3 landscape visible. But not if I use your code without this option. And i guess that this \pdfpagewidth=2\pdfpagewidth + your code is what is messing with the margin. On your pdf output do you observe a A3 landscape format  or does it looks like a A4 page ? Thank you.

Comment: I don't know how various pdf display programs work. All I know is that whatever "humongous" tableaus go on the verso pages will show up properly if they're printed on sheets of A3 paper. :-)

Comment: Hi Mico !Thanks foryour help. I finally got the thing to work but I still dontget  the measure. For me it works if \newenvironment{hugepage}%
  {\clearpage
   \pagestyle{empty} 
   \changepage{}{200mm}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}}
  {\addtocounter{page}{-1} 
   \clearpage
   \changepage{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}} 
 andadd \pdfpagewidth afterhugepage likeths \afterpage{%
\begin{hugepage}
\pdfpagewidth=2\pdfpagewidth \end{hugepage}}
but I don't undrstand why 200 mm is ok since the A3 page is now 420 mm wide ! 370 mm seemsmore correct to me but if y put 370 I get overflow of the text. I'm puzzled ... Thanks anyway !!!

Comment: Well, I'm really glad for your sake that you've got the changepage commands working, even though by rights it doesn't seem like this is how it's supposed to be done. Feel free to "check-mark" my answer any time. ;-)

Answer (score 12):

Of course `\pdfpagewidth` must be declared somewhere before changing format, but there is no need to restore A4 settings, since the A3 ones are within an environment.
On the other side the setting of `\changepage` are wrongly set; in facts the parameters of that macro must contain the difference between the original settings and the new settings therefore to switch to landscape A3 paper without changing the existing margins it suffices to write:

```
\changepage{}{210mm}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
```

where 210mm is the increase of the textwidth due to the larger available horizontal page size.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) (with a blank line either side) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Hi, Claudio! It's a great honour to have you with us. `:)`