# Foldable DIN A0 page within normal document

Tags: paper-size, book-design

This question is somewhat similar to this question: [Insert foldable A3 pages in an A4 document with active references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29668/insert-foldable-a3-pages-in-an-a4-document-with-active-references)

However it's not completely the same.

I want to have a foldable DIN A1/DIN A0 page, which contains a really big image, within my normal DIN A4 document.

Can this be achieved with `\changepage` command as well? If so, what should I expect, if I print the whole document?

Comment: Wow, what kind of image is that, if you don't mind my asking?

Comment: It's a class diagram with over 50 classes, which I unfortunately can't split, because it's expected to be in one graph.

Comment: That is what I have always disliked about UML. The syntax is so incredibly space-consuming; seems as if the boys never considered  *printing* diagrams for real pieces of software.

Comment: Have you tried it with `geometry` package? `\clearpage\newgeomtry{a0paper,margin=1in}` then insert the image followed by `\clearpage\newgeomtry{a4paper,margin=1in}` may be the solution.

Comment: See also [Change paper size in mid-document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6834/change-paper-size-in-mid-document)

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how you expect to print the document but typically pages of different sizes are printed in separate processes, then assembled to make the final product (the odd-sized pages being `tipped-in' to the main document).

My suggestion is to treat your A0 sheet as a separate (LaTeX) document and manually assemble it with the A4 sheets. If you need to reference it in the main document you can do something like `see diagram between pages n and n+1' so you don't have to fiddle with the main document's page numbering. You might consider putting your A0 sheet at the end of the main document which could make it easier for readers to find (and keep unfolded while reading about it).

Comment: Well yes. I could do that, but Unfortunately I have to hand in a digital version. Again, I could provide two separate pdfs, but would rather have one. Seems like it's not something that can be easily done with LaTeX.

Comment: You can use `pdftk` to assemble some PDF files.

Comment: @cherrung, Paul: you can use `pdfpages` to add pages of other PDFs inside your document easily. This is often done for appendices etc. and should support pages of different sizes as well.

Answer (score 4):

You should best make a separate PDF with your big image and include it in the main document using the `pdfpages` package. The `\includepdf` macro provided can insert one or multiple PDF pages either with the document page size or with the original page size. For the latter simply use the `fitpaper` option.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}
\lipsum% stands for some example paragraphs before the image
\afterpage{%  to place it direkt after the next page break, not direct after the text, to avoid a larger empty space
\includepdf[fitpaper=true]{big_image}%
}
\lipsum% stand for some example paragraphs after the image. The first parapraphs can still be placed on the page before the image

\end{document}
```

Here I made the example image using the following document:

```
% big_image.tex
\documentclass[a0paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=.999\textwidth,height=.999\textheight]{example-image}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

### How to include a page of a different format in a PDF

Either you integrate the LaTeX code into your document with all the advantages (e.g. same fonts) and disadvantages (messing around with different sizes) or you include the page manually using the package `pdfpages`.

You have to read the manual of pdfpages (=> `texdoc pdfpages` on command line)  carefully, there are many usefull options for your purposes. It is possible to include your picture full page, but how to do that may depend on your documentclass.

Comment: Please add some code which shows how to achieve this with `pdfpages`. "Read the manual" doesn't qualify as an answer. Also, why the headline?

Comment: I never add code if the OP does not offer a MWE.