# Figure on A3 page within A4 document

Tags: floats, paper-size, book-design

In my dissertation, I got some diagrams that don't fit a single (horizontal) A4 page. Hence I decided to print them on A3 pages that might be unfolded when reading. I followed the instructions in several posts, including this one:

[Insert foldable A3 pages in an A4 document with active references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29668/insert-foldable-a3-pages-in-an-a4-document-with-active-references)

My first attempt looks like this:

```
\newpage
\begingroup
\pdfpagewidth=2\pdfpagewidth
\noindent%\makebox[0pt][l]{%
\begin{figure}
%graphics go here
\caption{foo}
\end{figure}
\newpage
\endgroup
```

When replacing the figure with plain text, I indeed get a A3 landscape page within my document. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work for the figure-environment, since neither the graphics, nor the caption are displayed.

Please note that I want to reference the figures, hence `pdfpages` might not be an option.

Comment: In general you can't put a `figure`, which is a float, into a box, e.g. `\makebox[0pt][l]{..}`. Instead apply the box command to the content if `figure`. Also, in this case you should use `\clearpage` not `\newpage` to create a new page but clear all pending floats (`figure`s and `table`s) first. This way you insure that your `figure` is placed before the group ends.

Comment: The `hugepage` environment in the answer to the above linked question didn't work for you?

Comment: See also (not a duplicate): [How to include a picture over two pages, left part on left side, right on right (for books)?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23860)

Comment: AFAIR is the geometry package able to create different geometries within one document.

Comment: @UweZiegenhagen: Yes, but it doesn't allow you to change the paper size mid-document

Comment: Thanks for your replies!
@MartinScharrer: I don't get how your first comment is related to the question. And: I didn't get the hugepage-environment to work, most probably because I didn't know where to insert the "\pdfpagewidth=2\pdfpagewidth" command.

Comment: @gerrit: thanks for the hint, but that's not an alternative for me. I need to print large diagrams which have higher requirements to readability than e.g. a painting, etc.

Comment: @Chris: My first comment was a general one, as stated, and is related to the `\makebox[0pt][l]` in your code which got commented out. So apparently you tried placing a `figure` into a `\makebox`, so I thought to point out that this doesn't work at all.

Comment: Answers https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/109495/6865 your question?