# Saving A3 Landscape page to an A3 size pdf

Tags: printing

I did manage to put an A3 size page within the A4 document. It contains a landscape figure. My problem is how to save document in pdf format such that the A3 page appear as it is, and not scale down to an A4 pdf.

I'm using a Mac machine and the native 'save as print' functionality creates a pdf file where the A3 page is saved as an A4 page.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108440/insert-a3-page-with-figure-into-a4-document-with-active-references

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I Dont think so!

Comment: I don't understand the question then:-) the important bit being the local setting `\pdfpagewidth=2\pdfpagewidth` so that the pdf viewer doesn't crop that page to A4

Comment: This looks to me, as though the question is not a TeX one, but one concerning the viewing software, you are using. Please be more precise about what you are doing and what software you are using.