# Oversized (A4 height, but much wider) pages in A4 document - header / footer alignment needs to be changed

Tags: graphics, header-footer, paper-size, scrbook, scrpage2

I have to include a large graphic in a A4 document, the figure fits into an A4 height, but is much wider. I used `\pdfpagewidth=3.1\pdfpagewidth` to increase the paper size, and included the figure. I use `srcbook`(one-sided) with the header and footer aligned to the right. 
The problem with the oversized page is, that the header and footer are not moved to the final right end. Finally, the oversized page gets folded so that it fits in the printed thesis in A4, I want the header and footer on the page that you finally see when you open the book.

That is how I did it so far:

```
% Example to show oversized page with figure

\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,DIV14,BCOR15mm,oneside, headings=small,headsepline, appendixprefix]{scrbook}

\usepackage{graphicx}       % Package for Pictures
\usepackage[bf,footnotesize,width=.9\textwidth,format=hang]{caption}    

% Oneside option puts header and footer in centered alignment, this changes to right alignment
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\ohead{\headmark}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Literature Review - Experimental Work} 

A bit of text ….
\newpage
A bit of text again, just to show the header and footer on the usual A4 pages.

\newpage
\begingroup
\pdfpagewidth=3.1\pdfpagewidth
\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
{\includegraphics[height=227mm]{HistoricalOverview.pdf}}
\caption{Historical Overview}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

That is the output with the header and footer at the wrong horizontal position:
[image: Output]

How can I change the horizontal alignment of my header / footer? 
I had a look to `\changepage` and to [Insert A3 page with figure into A4 document with active references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108440/insert-a3-page-with-figure-into-a4-document-with-active-references) but I don't get it working.

Any advice helps, thanks. Gerlind

Comment: So you have an over-broad page? Perhaps cleanest is to have that one without headers/footers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the class doesn't measure the right margin, instead it measures the text width. So I did a bit of a hack and changed that. It looks ok to me, if you don't mind the decoration line running all along the top of the page. You can use a value for `\textwidth` that's more precise. I'm sure someone more expert can provide a more elegant solution!

Inside your group:

```
\begingroup
\pdfpagewidth=3.1\pdfpagewidth
\textwidth=590mm
\begin{figure}[p]
```