# Full width landscape image in koma script

Tags: floats, koma-script, classicthesis, landscape

I need an image the biggest possible and then show it in landscape. I use koma options in a classic thesis flavour. I don't find any solution to have it bigger than the textwidth but staying in the center of the page.

I have tried with

```
\KOMAoptions{paper=landscape}

\begin{addmargin}
```

can anyone help? no solution

Thank you

Comment: Well I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812892/change-paper-size-in-the-middle-of-a-latex-document) can help you or at least give you a clue, [this other](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108440/insert-a3-page-with-figure-into-a4-document-with-active-references) also. I don't know how to big is the image you need, and since you added only a snippet instead of a full MWE I don't know what else suggest you.

Comment: I would simply use `sidewaysfigure` provided by package `rotating`. No `landscape` option, no `addmargin` ...